# Oracle VirtualBox - Cursor Lost in Top Left Corner

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

In my Oracle VirtualBox 6.1, regularly, a square around 15cm x 15cm in the left top corner doesn't take the mouse click anymore (left and right). I'm not sure what causes it. It comes and goes at random.

Could't see anything obvious from the logs. I haven't moved the window, or resized it. The problem just appears and I have to either wait some time (30 mins, or more) or reboot.

The image is Ubuntu, I tried both Gnome and KDE Plasma to exclude an X problem.

What I've tried so far:
 * Resizing windows
 * Enable/disable mouse capture
 * Change the mouse settings to *USB Tablet* or *PS/2 Mouse*.
 * reload the mouse module with `rmmod` and `modprobe`

Nothing changes. Only workaround I found is to enable a second monitor and switch my apps to it, ignoring the first.

```
287:03:09.198303 VMMDev: SetVideoModeHint: Got a video mode hint (120x501x32)@(0x0),(1;0) at 0
287:03:09.202764 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
287:03:09.237392 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=1920 h=1057 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x2 origin=0,0
287:03:09.251669 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000001336b000 w=800 h=600 bpp=32 cbLine=0xC80 flags=0x1 origin=0,0
287:03:09.261604 GUI: UIMachineLogic: Guest-screen count changed
287:03:09.445216 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=800 h=600 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x2 origin=0,0
287:03:09.455684 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000001336b000 w=120 h=501 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1E0 flags=0x1 origin=0,0
287:03:09.456747 GUI: UIMachineLogic: Guest-screen count changed
287:03:09.558287 GUI: UIMachineView::sltPerformGuestResize: Sending guest size-hint to screen 0 as 120x501 if necessary
287:03:09.567996 GUI: UIMachineView::sltPerformGuestResize: Sending guest size-hint to screen 0 as 120x501 if necessary
287:03:10.363041 GUI: UIMachineView::sltPerformGuestResize: Sending guest size-hint to screen 0 as 1920x1057 if necessary
287:03:10.375516 VMMDev: SetVideoModeHint: Got a video mode hint (1920x1057x32)@(0x0),(1;0) at 0
287:03:10.381757 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
287:03:10.537721 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=120 h=501 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x2 origin=0,0
287:03:10.550348 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000001336b000 w=120 h=501 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1E0 flags=0x1 origin=0,0
287:03:10.551218 GUI: UIMachineLogic: Guest-screen count changed
287:03:10.577517 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=120 h=501 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x2 origin=0,0
287:03:10.579120 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=00000000114f7000 w=1920 h=1057 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1E00 flags=0x1 origin=0,0
287:03:10.588438 GUI: UIMachineLogic: Guest-screen count changed
```

Comment: Please install ```xev``` and run it from a terminal. Move the white box into the "dead zone" and click into it. Does ```xev``` recognize your clicks?

Comment: Thanks @dirdi. I just ran into the problem. `xev` doesn't recognize the clicks

Comment: Then it is probably a problem with the host system.

Comment: Couldn't find any known bugs or anyone with the same problem.

Comment: What is your host OS? Can you run ```xev``` on it and check if the host recognizes the click? You could also run ```xprop``` on the host and click into the dead zone. Maybe there is a transparent other window that blocks the clicks.

Comment: Running on windows 10. Outside of the VirtualBox there is no sign of issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To everyone driven mad by this: The issue is caused by the guest additions. It is unpractical to work without those.

[This post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=79034) contains a bunch of good information. Drag & Drop seems to be the issue here. Dragging a file from host to guest seem to restore the functionality, so I'll run with DnD disabled from now on and hopefully the issue will not present itself again

Comment: This easy workaround helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but looks like you hit a virtualization bug linked to Hot Corners, have a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1019918) to deactivate it under Gnome, there is probably a way to deactivate it under KDE Plasma, too.